# I get this error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to do inserts into my database to "populate" it, and all inserts work fine, except for the "reservation" insert...
When I try to insert my reservation table:

```
Insert Into Reservation
(ReservNum, ReserveDate, NumOfPassengers, sheduledTime, ActualPickupTime, ActualTime, PricePaid, HourlyRate, SalaryEarned)
VALUES
('24333', '2015-10-15', '6', '20', '7:04', '22', '$15', '34', '$12.47');
```

I get this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`oma`.`Reservation`, CONSTRAINT `Reservation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_CustomerID`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`CustomerID`))

Here are my create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
Phone VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Location (
Address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Latitude VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
Longitude VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Address));


CREATE TABLE Employee (
EmployeeID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID));


CREATE TABLE Truck (
LicensePlate CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
color VARCHAR(45) NULL,
capacity VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LicensePlate));

CREATE TABLE Shifts (
ShiftTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ShiftTime));

CREATE TABLE EmployeeShifts (
DesiredShift DATETIME NOT NULL,
EmployeeWorking INT NULL,
DateOfShift DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(DesiredShift, EmployeeWorking),
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeWorking) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (DesiredShift) REFERENCES Shifts(ShiftTime));

CREATE TABLE Reservation (
ReservNum INT NOT NULL,
ReserveDate DATE NULL,
PickupTime VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
NumOfPassengers INT NULL,
sheduledTime VARCHAR(45) NULL,
ActualPickupTime VARCHAR(45),
ActualTime VARCHAR(45),
SalaryEarned VARCHAR(10),
PricePaid VARCHAR(45),
HourlyRate DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
Customer_CustomerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Truck_LicensePlate char(20) NOT NULL,
Employee_EmployeeID_Driver INT,
Location_Address_Pickup VARCHAR(100),
Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger INT,
Location_Address_Drop VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (ReservNum),
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID),
FOREIGN KEY (Truck_LicensePlate) REFERENCES Truck (LicensePlate),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Driver) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Pickup) REFERENCES Location (Address),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Drop) REFERENCES Location (Address));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Customer_Customer_ID` column in `Reservation` is an `AUTO INCREMENT`:

> ```
> Customer_CustomerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
> ```

meaning that if you don't specify the value when `INSERT`-ing, one will be automatically assigned to it. You didn't specify it in the `INSERT` and so the value automatically assigned to it didn't exist in the `Customers` table, which violated the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint:

> ```
> FOREIGN KEY (Customer_CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID),
> ```

To solve this,

- Remove the `AUTO_INCREMENT` from the `Customer_CustomerID` column. You should be able to insert now, since the column can be `NULL`, in which case the `FOREIGN KEY` is not an issue.
- Or, if you want to assign a Customer to the Reservation, make sure a row exists in the `Customer` table, and pass the `Customer_Id` to the `INSERT INTO Reservation`. For instance, like this:

  ```
  INSERT INTO Customers( Name ) VALUES ('Test');

  INSERT INTO Reservation (
      ReservNum, Customer_Customer_ID,
      ReserveDate, NumOfPassengers, 
      sheduledTime, ActualPickupTime, ActualTime,
      PricePaid, HourlyRate, SalaryEarned
  )
  VALUES (
      '24333', LAST_INSERT_ID(),
      '2015-10-15', '6',
      '20', '7:04', '22',
      '$15', '34', '$12.47'
  );
  ```

The [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) gets the value from the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in the last `INSERT`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Sorry just confused about what you meant by "make sure a row exists in the Customer table, and pass the Customer_Id to the INSERT INTO Reservation."

Comment: Do you mean like this?                                                                      Insert Into Reservation
(ReservNum, ReserveDate, NumOfPassengers, sheduledTime, ActualPickupTime, ActualTime, PricePaid, HourlyRate, SalaryEarned, Customer_CustomerID)
VALUES
('24333', '2015-10-15', '6', '20', '7:04', '22', '$15', '34', '$12.47', '');

Comment: Yes, except use an actual value from the `Customers` table as the last value, not `''`. Try `SELECT * FROM Customers` and pick a `CustomerID`.

Comment: Okay that worked..Now I have one last problem. I get this error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`oma`.`Reservation`, CONSTRAINT `Reservation_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Truck_LicensePlate`) REFERENCES `Truck` (`LicensePlate`))

Comment: Would that be the same thing? Just add in truck_licenseplate to the insert reservation, with its value from the truck table>

Comment: That's more or less the same question. Make sure you pass an existing `LicensePlate` from the `Truck` table to the `INSERT INTO Reservation`; it is `Truck_LicensePlate CHAR(20) NOT NULL` so it's mandatory.

Comment: Yes exactly - you will need to provide values for all the `NOT NULL` columns and all the `FOREIGN KEY`s: the `Reservation` is a relationship between all those entities (Customer, Truck, Driver, Pickup, Passenger, Drop).

Comment: Okay yes I figured it out

Comment: Kenney I do have one more question if you're up to answering it. Was it wrong for me to have both "Location_Address_Pickup" and "Location_Address_Drop" refer to "Address" in the location table, if they are both supposed to have different values?

Comment: No that's fine. You can have multiple foreign keys to the same table, no problem.